# How to sync two lists oneway?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox, listbox

I have a list of Label objects presented in a ListBox. The Labels can be assigned Fonts which may be selected from a ComboBox. The Label object references the Font object through the FontId.

When selecting a Label from the ListBox, the according Font object shall be selected in the ComboBox. However, selecting a Font from the ComboBox shall 'assign' the font to the selected Label without selecting a matching item in the ListBox. That's why I called that 'oneway' sync.

My current code syncs the two lists in both directions, i.e. selecting a Font object from the ComboBox results in selecting the Label with the corresponding font id in the ListBox.

Below you'll find the ViewModel with the Label and Font models as well as the XAML.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class NotifyPropertyChanged : System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void RaisePropertyChanged(string prop)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
            }
        }
    }

    public class ViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public class Label : NotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public Label(string name, int id)
            {
                this.name = name;
                this.fontId = id;
            }

            string name;
            public string Name 
            {
                get { return name; }
                set
                {
                    if (name == value) return;
                    name = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
                }
            }

            int fontId;
            public int FontId
            {
                get { return fontId; }
                set
                {
                    if (fontId == value) return;
                    fontId = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("FontId");
                }
            }
        }

        public class Font : NotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public Font(string face, int id)
            {
                this.face = face;
                this.id = id;
            }

            int id;
            public int Id
            {
                get { return id; }
                set
                {
                    if (id == value) return;
                    id = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Id");
                }
            }

            string face;
            public string Face
            {
                get { return face; }
                set
                {
                    if (face == value) return;
                    face = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Face");
                }
            }
        }

        List<Label> labels = new List<Label>
        {
            new Label("City", 1),
            new Label("Road", 13),
            new Label("POI", 17),
            new Label("Favorite", 42)
        };

        public IEnumerable<Label> Labels
        {
            get { return labels; }
        }

        List<Font> fonts = new List<Font>
        {
            new Font("Arial 20", 1),
            new Font("Arial 10", 13),
            new Font("Arial 8", 17),
            new Font("Arial 12", 42),
            new Font("Times 12", 47),
            new Font("Times 18", 11)
        };

        public IEnumerable<Font> Fonts
        {
            get { return fonts; }
        }

        Label curLabel;
        public Label CurrentLabel
        {
            get { return curLabel; }
            set
            {
                if (curLabel == value) return;
                curLabel = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentLabel");
            }
        }

        Font curFont;
        public Font CurrentFont
        {
            get { return curFont; }
            set
            {
                if (curFont == value) return;
                curFont = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentFont");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="216" ResizeMode="NoResize" SizeToContent="Width">
    <WrapPanel Margin="10">
        <ListBox Name="labelListBox" Width="160" Height="130" Margin="10"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Labels}"
                 DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentLabel}"
                 SelectedValuePath="FontId"/>

        <ComboBox Name="fontComboBox" Width="160" Height="30" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Fonts}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Face"
                  SelectedValuePath="Id"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding ElementName=labelListBox, Path=SelectedValue}"/>
    </WrapPanel>
</Window>
```

And the code-behind:
using System.Windows;

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is setting `Mode` of the Binding (in ComboBox) to `OneWay`:

```
<ComboBox Name="fontComboBox" Width="160" Height="30" Margin="10" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Fonts}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Face"
          SelectedValuePath="Id"
          SelectedValue="{Binding ElementName=labelListBox, Path=SelectedValue,
                                  Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Now when selecting in ListBox, its `SelectedValue` will change, making the SelectedValue of ComboBox change. The `SelectedValuePath` resolves the actual SelectedValue to the `Id` member and will select the matched item. Because we set the Binding's Mode to `OneWay`, selecting item from ComboBox as well as changing the `SelectedValue` of the ComboBox won't reflect to the ListBox's SelectedValue.

Comment: Thanks, that solves it for my example I posted. Unfortunately not in my project - still figuring out the critical difference to this mockup...

Answer (score 0):

Minor correction in your xaml as below. Hope this is what you want and it helps.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="216" ResizeMode="NoResize" SizeToContent="Width">
<WrapPanel Margin="10">
    <ListBox Name="labelListBox" Width="160" Height="130" Margin="10"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Labels}"
             DisplayMemberPath="Name"
             SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentLabel}"
             FontSize="{Binding ElementName=fontComboBox , Path=SelectedValue.Id}"
             FontFamily="{Binding ElementName=fontComboBox, Path=SelectedValue.Face}"/>

    <ComboBox Name="fontComboBox" Width="160" Height="30" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Top"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Fonts}"                  
              DisplayMemberPath="Face"
              SelectedValue="{Binding CurrentFont}"/>
   </WrapPanel>
```